How can I control access to events based on user role and event type?
I want to be able to offer events targeted to different groups of users. The documentation suggests that I can do this using CiviCRM ACLs, but that appears to only offer access control for a given event. My events are categorised by type – i have about 8 different event types set up, covering perhaps 100 events.
Can I set up an ACL which gives access to all events of a given type, such that I can then add a further event and the access controls will apply based on the event type I select for the event?
This seems like an obvious approach, but the UI suggests otherwise.

guessing not Drupal - otherwise webform + civigroup synch + drupal roles might be a solution for someone who is on Drupal and sees this

May be using ACLWhere clause hook can be achieved what you need
or may be using https://civicrm.org/extensions/member-only-event as an alternate approach

Hi. Yes, I've looked at both of those options. The extension doesn't give me sufficiently fine-grained control. An ACL-based approach, maybe leveraging the hook you mention, could potentially do it, but I don't have the coding chops for that. Could you help?
